# how to install the 'pysparse' package using Enthought python, Windows XP SP3?

Tags: python, dll, importerror, enthought

I am running on a Windows XP SP3 and currently have fresh installations of the following:

- Enthought python Dist. version  7.1-2 (32-bit)
  --> which set up a Python 2.7.2
- pysparse-1.1.1.win32-py2.7.exe  downloaded from - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pysparse
- microsoft visual studio 2010

I need pysparse inorder to install and use 'fipy'.

From some reason any attempt include a .pyd file from pysparse e.g :

```
>>> from pysparse import jdsym
```

ends with the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I should point out that installing other packages from the same link and including .pyd files worked fine.

Any help would be incredibly great.

Comment: Pysparse-1.1.1.win32-py2.7.exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pysparse requires numpy-MKL from the same page. Specifically, jdsym.pyd depends on libiomp5md.dll 5.0 which is not included in EPD but in numpy-MKL.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the compiled Pysparse library for Windows system from the following website:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ 
Then just by running the related EXE file you can install the pysparse and import to your code.

Comment: That is exactly what he said he did... well I supose he double-clicked to install...